# Transposing data in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel

In **Column A** I have a number. In **Column B** I have a name as well as data that should go in columns **C** and **D**.

How can I turn this:

[image: what I have]

into this:

[image: what I need]

?

Comment: Is First name supposed to be Abbruzzese Gabriele? Also do you mean row or column?

Comment: Can you provide your data more clear and understandable way?

Comment: I hope now's better

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assume: Every 3 rows of old record = 1 row of new record

1. Enter into C1: `=B2` and copy down to C2:C999
2. Enter into D1: `=B3` and copy down to D2:D999
3. Enter into E1: `=MOD(ROW(E1) ,3) = 1` and copy down to E2:E999
4. Copy column C:E
5. Select C1 > Edit > Paste Special > Value ( `Alt-E > S > V > Enter` )
6. Turn on AutoFilter: Data > Filter > AutoFilter ( `Alt-D > F > F` )
7. Select `FALSE` in column E auto filter drop-down list
8. Select row 2:999 > Right click > Delete
9. Delete dummy column E:E
10. Turn off auto filter: Data > Filter > AutoFilter ( `Alt-D > F > F` )

Comment: That's pure binary-minded information :D
You win.

Comment: I found [another answer](http://superuser.com/a/402958/43356) which is also good.

Answer (score 1):

`copy - paste special - transpose`

Comment: it works but I shoud do it manually for a lot of rows...

Comment: record a macro? Is it always the same spacing?

Comment: Might not fit the use case which the OP asked about, but it certainly fits the *title* of this question, and as such was verys useful to me.